# How to read CLOB type to Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I declared a SqlParameter like this:

```
//some code here
declareParameter(new SqlParameter("name", Types.CLOB)
compile()
//some code
```

Now I want to read it, but don't know which Java type to use. Probably String is good?

```
//some code here
String getAll = (String) res.get("name");
```

CLOB has JSON on it.

Comment: @Abra Thats not JDBC, thats a stored procedure

Comment: @Abra Yes, I am doing it at Spring Boot